# SQL Server using Hashbytes for non sensitive data

Tags: sql, sql-server, hashbytes

I am wondering why there would be a reason to use the hashbytes algorithm when the data below does not contain any passwords or other sensitive data like this. Is there really a need to use this if you are not dealing with passwords, credit card numbers etc?

```
   select  distinct
    @reportIdLeiDuplicates,
    wp.CrmPartyId,
    wp.GtId,  
    convert(varchar(20), 
            hashbytes('SHA1', isnull(wp.CrmPartyId, '') + isnull(wp.GtId, '') ),    
            2),
```

Comment: It depends on what you mean by sensitive data.  Under European regulations, unless you need to know my name *(and have asked, and have permission, etc)*, you shouldn't store my name.  So, instead "tokens" are stored.  These tokens can quite reasonably be hashes.  *(Be very careful that **your** definition of "sensitive" may not match the **legal** definition.  Search for Client Confidential Information, or Personally Identifiable Information, etc.  Then ISO 27001 and then GDPR or whatever legislation applies to you.)*

Comment: @MatBailie The IDs don't look like they are PII though.  Something like a social security number could be, but this just looks like a database ID.

Comment: I'm going to suggest that the author is trying to create a new unique ID of the two. It doesn't look very effective to me because you cannot reverse a hashbyte back to the original value using SQL.  It would have been better to convert them to string then a (var)binary value that can be converted back to source.

Comment: @TJB - There is nothing in the actual question to suggest that it is limited only to the code snippet added below it.  Thus...  `It depends on what you mean by sensitive data.` and my extrapolation of that.

Comment: Another possible reason... It can be used as a "CHECKSUM" that has a reduced risk of collisions.

Comment: @K1205 . . . Obviously for this example, `hashbytes()` is *not* serving a function to obfuscate the data -- because the original ids are in the result set.  This looks like an attempt to combine two ids or to create a "check sum" like column (as explained in other comments).